# Interactjs How To Change Start Position Drag Item

Tags: javascript, html, css, interactjs

my dragitem initially appears in the upper left. I want to give a space of 100 pixels from the top and left at the opening. but I have to do this with interactjs own code, not css. because if i do it with css the scroll setting is broken

```js
interact('.dragitem')
    .draggable({
        inertia: true,
        modifiers: [
        interact.modifiers.restrictRect({
            restriction: 'parent',
            endOnly: true
        })
        ],
        autoScroll: true,
        listeners: {
            move: dragMoveListener
        }
        
    })
    function dragMoveListener (event) {
    var target = event.target
    var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx
    var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy
    target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y)
    }
    window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener
```

```css
.drag-container {
  width:1000px;
  height:1000px;
  background:red;
}
.dragitem {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs/dist/interact.min.js"></script>
<div class="drag-container">
  <div class="dragitem">drag me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the starting position in style, data-x and data-y directly in HTML

```html
<div class="dragitem" style="transform: translate(100px, 100px);" data-x="100" data-y="100">drag me</div>
```

```js
interact('.dragitem')
    .draggable({
        inertia: true,
        modifiers: [
        interact.modifiers.restrictRect({
            restriction: 'parent',
            endOnly: true
        })
        ],
        autoScroll: true,
        listeners: {
            move: dragMoveListener
        }
    })
    function dragMoveListener (event) {
      var target = event.target

      var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx
      var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy
      target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
      target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
      target.setAttribute('data-y', y)
    }
    window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener
```

```css
.drag-container {
  width:1000px;
  height:1000px;
  background:red;
}
.dragitem {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs/dist/interact.min.js"></script>
<div class="drag-container">
  <div class="dragitem" style="transform: translate(100px, 100px);" data-x="100" data-y="100">drag me</div>
</div>
```