# Interact js set position and size programatically

Tags: interactjs

I use interact js 1.10.11

and I want to change the position (top, left) and size (width, height) of my elements with inputs.

Currently I change the css value

```
element.css('top', '50px') ;
element.css('width', '500px') ;
```

It works but when I drag my element, it teleports to another place on the page and I can't explain it.

How can I do this properly ?

Comment: Does it answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71556034/interactjs-how-to-change-start-position-drag-item

Comment: I'm not on this projet anymore, I can't test this for the moment, I tell you when I can try it